# Sublime text xml replace regex result

Tags: regex, xml, replace, find, sublimetext

I have a problem with replacing regex result in multiple xml tags in Sumbilme Text.

I have xml code with multiple tags `<startDate>` in different groups like this:

```
<group1>
  <id>123</id>
  <startDate>2011-11-11</startDate>
  <city>New York</city>
  .
  .
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>456</id>
  <startDate>2013-10-01</startDate>
  <classCode>123</classCode>
  .
  .
</group2>
<group1>
  <id>789</id>
  <startDate>2016-01-17</startDate>
  <city>Washington</city>
  .
  .
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>135</id>
  <startDate>2013-12-22</startDate>
  <classCode>234</classCode>
  .
  .
</group2>
```

I would like to replace every tag `<startDate>(...some date...)</startDate>` only in a `<group2>` to `<startDate1>(...some date...)</startDate1>`

Text in brackets (...some date...) are different.

I started to find this tags and I used this code:

```
(?=.*<startDate>)(?=.*</startDate>
                    <classCode>)
```

And it works. Sublime found every tag `<startDate>(...some date...)</startDate>` in `<group2>`. 
But I have a problem to replace text in founded tags.

I tried to put this code into 'Replace' line:

```
(?=.*<startDate1>)(?=.*</startDate1>
                    <classCode>)
```

It didn't work.

So I found another option.

In 'Find' line I put:

```
(?=.*(<startDate)(>))(?=.*(</startDate)(>
                    <classCode>))
```

And in 'Replace' line:

```
$1 1 $2 $3 1 $4
```

But the result was:

```
.
.
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>456</id>
  <startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate 1 > </startDate 1 >
                    <classCode><startDate>2015-11-02</startDate>
                    <classCode>123</classCode>
```

So my target tags didn't change but new were added...

And I would like to have this result:

```
<group1>
  <id>123</id>
  <startDate>2011-11-11</startDate>
  <city>New York</city>
  .
  .
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>456</id>
  <startDate1>2013-10-01</startDate1>
  <classCode>123</classCode>
  .
  .
</group2>
```

Is there any way not to replace tags names manualy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<startDate>([\d-]+)<\/startDate>(?=\s*<classCode>)
```

Replace with:

```
<startDate1>$1</startDate1>
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/3obgA3/5)

Comment: It works in regex101.com, but in Sublime not. Replacing returns me empty tag... `<group1>
  <id>123</id>
  <startDate>2011-11-11</startDate>
  <city>New York</city>
  .
  .
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>456</id>
  <>2013-10-01</startDate>
  <classCode>123</classCode>
  .
  .
</group2>
<group1>
  <id>789</id>
  <startDate>2016-01-17</startDate>
  <city>Washington</city>
  .
  .
</group1>
<group2>
  <id>135</id>
  <>2013-12-22</startDate>
  <classCode>234</classCode>
  .
  .
</group2>`  And the closing tag </startDate> doesn't change.

Comment: @boogie Updated. Try again.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching for this: `(<\/?)startDate>` and replacing with `\1startDate1>`.

This looks way too simple. Can you show me an input that would fool this regex?

#### Update

Based on the updated question this is what I could come up with:

Regex: `(?s)startDate>((?:.(?!\/group[013456789]))*)(?=\/group2)`
Replacement: `startDate1>\1`

You'll have to run 'Replace All' twice to replace every required tag. I'm checking if I can make it run only once.

Also, let me suggest XSLT for this kind of tasks.

Comment: My previous post wasn't precisely enough. I add information about the same name of tags in different tags group. And I need to change name of the repeated tag only in one group. Could you verify my problem now?